# HttpClient POST request using x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: angular

I'm trying to make a POST request with `x-www-form-urlencoded`content type header as follows:

```
login(username, password): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post('/login', {
      username: username,
      password: password
      },
      {
        headers: new HttpHeaders()
          .set('Content-Type', 'x-www-form-urlencoded')
      }
      );
```

Unfortunately my API says that I sent empty username and password.

so I decided to make a postman request to my login endpoint and see where the problem comes from, and the postman request did return the username and password.

How comes that when I'm posting from postman my API return my username and password and when I post from my Angular app my API returns empty values? Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 148):

You're posting JSON data to the API instead of form data.
The snippet below should work.

```
login(username, password): Observable<any> {
  const body = new HttpParams()
    .set('username', username)
    .set('password', password);

  return this.http.post('/login',
    body.toString(),
    {
      headers: new HttpHeaders()
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: After a lot of search this solution worked! A lot of old guides out there using the old HttpClient... :) Thank you!

Comment: I was only able to get Owain's solution working by not performing a "toString()" on the body.

Comment: that what I need

Comment: you sir are a legend \m/

Comment: yay thanks! I've tried searching for your answer everywhere

Comment: Best option to pass parameters in the body

Comment: @DiegoSarmiento What do you mean?

Comment: @OwainvanBrakel I needed to pass some values in the body and .set('month', month) was the way to do it

Comment: The `Content-Type` header is not necessary when using `HttpParams`, at least for Angular 8.  The content type seems to default to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` when the body is `HttpParams`.

Comment: removing `toString` from `body.toString()` worked for me. hopefully this will help someone else save some time!

Answer (score 36):

There is an easier way than the others approaches described here.

This is what worked for me with Angular 7:

```
const payload = new HttpParams()
  .set('username', username)
  .set('password', password);

this.http.post(url, payload);
```

No need to explicitly set the header with this approach.

Note that the HttpParams object is immutable. So doing something like the following won't work, it will give you an empty body:

```
const payload = new HttpParams();
payload.set('username', username);
payload.set('password', password);

this.http.post(url, payload);
```

Comment: where did you find the content?

Comment: it looks like content and body are synonymous

Comment: The fact that `HttpParams` is immutable tripped me up.  Took a while to figure out why it gave an empty body.

Answer (score 2):

You can as well as load your data from an object

```
login(username, password): Observable<any> {
    const body = new HttpParams({
        fromObject: {
            username,
            password,
            ...extraData, // if any 
        }
    });

    return this.http.post('/login',
        body.toString(),
        {
            headers: new HttpHeaders()
                .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can to make a post request as below.

```
login(email:string, password:string):Observable<User>{
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    let params = new HttpParams().set('user', JSON.stringify({email: email,password:password}));
    return this.http.post<User>(`${MEAT_API_AUX}/login`,
    {},{headers: headers,params:params})
        .do(user => this.user = user);
}
```

after that you have to make subscribe.