# Angular 5 HttpClient: Send POST params as URL encoded string

Tags: javascript, angular

Angular 5.0.1

I'm looking at the docs for Angular HttpClient: https://angular.io/guide/http, 
but I can't seem to figure how to send POST params as a URLEncoded string instead of a JSON string. For instance, my Java http clients will send like this as default:

```
username=test%40test.com&password=Password1&rolename=Admin
```

But Angular wants to send as Json by default:

```
{"username":"test@test.com","password":"Password1","rolename":"Admin"}
```

Here's my code currently:

```
    let body = {
      username: "test@test.com",
      password: "Password1",
      rolename: "Admin"
    };

 let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");


    this.http.post(this.baseUrl, body, {
      headers: headers,
    })
      .subscribe(resp => {
      console.log("response %o, ", resp);
    });
```

I've also tried adding HttpParams:

```
let  httpParams = new HttpParams();
httpParams.append("username", "test@test.com");
httpParams.append("password", "Password1");
httpParams.append("rolename", "Admin");

...
headers: headers,
      params: httpParams
```

But HttpParams seem to have no effect.

Any idea how to URL encode the request instead of Json?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HttpClient POST request using x-www-form-urlencoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46714480/httpclient-post-request-using-x-www-form-urlencoded)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`append()` returns a **new** `HttpParams` object, so you'll need to make a slight modification to your `httpParams` code. Try this:

```
let httpParams = new HttpParams()
    .append("username", "test@test.com")
    .append("password", "Password1")
    .append("rolename", "Admin");
```

In the code above, we chain our `append` calls, creating a new `HttpParams` object on each call. The last time we call `append`, the `HttpParams` object returned will contain all of the previously appended parameters.

Comment: Ah yes, good catch that looks like it was the issue. As a note, looks like content type header is unnecessary as well.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. httpParams is still empty after this :(

Comment: Seems great. But how we can add the whole object as a bulk operation and why should we add the parameters one by one?! 
Any answer idea is appreciated as I have lost a couple of hours trying to figure out how can I send a simple JS object from Angular 5.

Answer (score 1):

That is because `HttpParam` is immutable.

You can read [why here](https://angular.io/guide/http#immutability)

In short:

```
let httpParams = new HttpParams()
    .append("username", "test@test.com")
    .append("password", "Password1")
    .append("rolename", "Admin");
```

> Because the app may retry requests, the interceptor chain may process
>   an individual request multiple times. If requests were mutable, a
>   retried request would be different than the original request.
>   Immutability ensures the interceptors see the same request for each
>   try.

Answer (score 0):

Supply the `HttpParams` object as the `body` argument for `post()`. That way, you will send form data as the request body instead of JSON. Also, the `params` option is not needed.

Here's an example:

```
const body = new HttpParams()
  .set('username', 'test@test.com')
  .set('password', 'Password1')
  .set('rolename', 'Admin');

this.httpClient.post(url, body, {
  headers: new HttpHeaders()
    .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
});
```

The `HttpParams` class is immutable. All mutation operations will return a new instance. You'll need to chain the `set()` calls to preserve the previously added parameters. You can use both `set()` and `append()`.