# Angular 5 HttpClient request using x-www-form-underloded

Tags: .net, angular, http, post, httpclient

I'm trying to make a POST request with x-www-form-urlencoded, the backend is using .NET and I definetely need to POST in that way, because it is not working the request by sending a JSON.
My component is the next one.

```
sendLead(model, API_ENDPOINT) {
const body = new URLSearchParams();
body.set('company_type', this.model.company_type);
body.set('user_id', this.model.user_id);
body.set('user_name', this.model.user_name);
body.set('user_email', this.model.user_email);
body.set('user_tel', this.model.user_tel);
body.set('user_company', this.model.user_company);
body.set('city', this.model.city);

const options = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
};

this.http
  .post(this.API_ENDPOINT, body.toString(), options).subscribe();  }
```

By requesting the POST with Angular I get the following error

```
{successful_register: false, error: "'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"}
```

By requesting the POST with Postman I get the following answer

```
"{\"successful_register\": \"1\", \"error\": null}"
```

Comment: I see no error in javascript code. Have you tried debugging your backend?

Comment: @ŁukaszSzcześniak I’m not authorized to manipulate the backend 

Comment: Try to see what request goes out of your web browser (for example in Chrome Network Tools) and compare it with one you send through Postman.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HttpClient POST request using x-www-form-urlencoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46714480/httpclient-post-request-using-x-www-form-urlencoded)