# sending JSON to Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express

I read many posts about how to send json to express via post but none worked or fixed my issue.

my issue is that when reading `req.body` where `req` is the request object
i get an output like this : `{ '{"z":"z"}': '' }` for this obejct i sent `{z:"z"}`

That is not expected and not any kind of behavior is saw before.

this si the angular httpClient request :

```
return new Promise((res,rej)=>{
        this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/Auth/Login",{z:"z"},{headers:new HttpHeaders('Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded')})
            .toPromise()
              .then(
              response =>{
               res(response)
              }
              ).catch(
                  err=>{
                      rej(err)
                  }
              )
    })
```

This is the server code :

```
router.route('/Login').all(function (req, res, next) {
    next();
}).post(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body);})
```

what i want is to get the same object i sent that is it.

Help !

Comment: have you tried 'Content-Type:application/json'

Comment: That creates an OPTIONS request ( preflight request ) and it doesn't get a good response and the requesst fails. i had the chrome extension on but didn't do anything

Comment: can you try same api from postman.

Comment: I did try that, It works perfectly when i send with x-www-form-urlencoded but not with raw :`{z:"z"}` which is what i want to send

Comment: did you change it to json in case of raw?

Comment: I send exactly this in raw : " {z:"z"} " without the quotes at first

Comment: have you tried this `app.use(bodyParser.json())`

Comment: Yes, i use that already. the project is generated using the official express generator, so technically all best options are there.

Comment: then it should work.

Comment: Could you just try it out yourself, using angular httpclient  as sender?

Comment: use htppClient, NOT the "old" http

Comment: http is just a local name for the injected HttpClient
`constructor(private http:HttpClient){...}`

Comment: have you had a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46714480/httpclient-post-request-using-x-www-form-urlencoded/46714814 question?

Comment: @ShyamBabu I did try that, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In service (or where you use connection with api) use `HttpClient` from `@angular/common/http` - because only in the `HttpClient` you can use `HttpHeaders`.

Example with simple service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  toparams = function ObjecttoParams(obj) {
    var p = [];
    for (var key in obj) {
      p.push(key + '=' + encodeURIComponent(obj[key]));
    }
    return p.join('&');
  };

  login(): any {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      let obj = { z: "z" };
      this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/Login", this.toparams(obj), {headers:new HttpHeaders('Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded')})
        .toPromise()
        .then( response => {
            res(response)
          }
        ).catch(err => {
            rej(err)
          }
        )
    })
  };
}
```

In module:

```
import { HttpModule } from "@angular/http"
...
imports: [
  ....
  HttpModule
],
```

Node.js + express example:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express()
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded bodies

app.all("/*", function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Cache-Control, Pragma, Origin, Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With, X-Auth");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST");
    return next();
});

app.route('/Login').all(function(req, res, next) {
    next();
}).post(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.json(req.body)
});

app.listen(3000)
```

Now when you send `{ z: "z" }` api will return the same object he will not parse it to JSON.

Would not it be easier to get JSON?

Comment: It worked, But isn't this just a workaround with the son to params parsing ?