# Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded is not working in angular 6

Tags: angular, http-headers

Trying to snd request with data encoded in url.
Using angular 6,  HttpClient for that.

```
private url = "http://localhost/login.php";
private httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' })
};

constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

login(email: string, password: string){
    return this.http.post(this.url, {username: email, password: password}, this.httpOptions);
}
```

As I understand 'Content-Type' should encode this:

```
{username: email, password: password}
```

Into this:

```
username=email&password=password
```

With values of course.

But in my case, URL encoded Form Data is the same (dev tools result):

```
{"username":"eee@eee.com","password":"eeee"}:
```

Can you tell me how is that possible to get a normal result?
Since this one, cant be simply $_POST'ed back-end side.

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/q/46714480/3001761

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't find that in 10mins... 
Will remove the question.