# HttpClient POST fails on Angular 6 when upgrading from AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-httpclient

I'm upgrading my application from Angular 1.6 to Angular 6 and I'm stuck in the login screen. Below is a code snippet of what I am trying to do -

```
const body = new URLSearchParams();
body.set('username', 'admin')
body.set('password', 'admin');

this.http.post('/log-in',
  body,
  {
    headers: new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
  }
).subscribe((response: Response) => {
  // Do something here 
}
```

This is the error I get even though the response from the server is a 200 -

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.js:1514)
at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:3811)
at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:498)
at invokeTask (zone.js:1744)
at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (zone.js:1781)
```

Clearly, the response expected is a JSON but I am receiving a HTML page

```
{error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)   
at XMLHtt…, text: "<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html lang="en" layout ng-app="pfs…rc="scripts/index.js"></script>↵↵</body>↵</html>↵"}
```

I've searched a lot to figure out how to fix this but have made no progress so far. Tried the suggestions in

[HttpClient POST request using x-www-form-urlencoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46714480/httpclient-post-request-using-x-www-form-urlencoded?rq=1)

[How to force Angular2 to POST using x-www-form-urlencoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39863317/how-to-force-angular2-to-post-using-x-www-form-urlencoded/39864307#39864307)

But neither of it fixed the problem. I also tried changing the **responseType** of the httpOptions and still facing the same error.

This is the working AngularJS (1.6) code -

```
var postHeaders = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
};    

$http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/log-in',
      data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike(
        {username: username, password: password}),
      headers: postHeaders,
    }).then(function (success) {
      // Do something
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this is because what you are posting to your back-end is incorrectly formatted so it's throwing an error and returning a HTML page. You shouldn't be sending a `URLSearchParams` object as your `body`, you should send a regular object:

```
const body = {
    username: 'admin',
    password: 'admin',
};
```

Comment: I tried the above suggested along with the other two suggestions from the stackoverflow answers in the links I have added to my question - one of it is what you see in my question. None of it worked. But I found what I needed to do to make it work. I'll post it below as an answer. Thanks for you suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this work after I did this - I had to add the following responseType to my options

```
return this.http.post('http://localhost/api/v1/log-in',
  body, { responseType: 'text' as 'json' }
)
```

Previously when I added responseType as 'text' I kept getting an error about a type mismatch. The key for me was to set it as *'text' as 'json'*.