# Angular HttpClient: Post method does not set parameter correctly

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, httpclient

There is a post request inside my method `transmitProject(project: ProjectModel): Observable<boolean>` via the `HttpClient` where I would like to post data to my backend:

-- *inside my `transmitProject`-method*

```
const params = {
   projectId: project.projectId,
   description: documentation.description,
   // some other attributes ...
};

return this.http.post(this.conf.url, params).pipe(
   map(response => {
      console.log(response);
      return true;
   })
);
```

... until here everyhting works fine. But the request sets the post data in json format. For testing the backend-server return the dumped $_POST variable -> null.

**Request Payload:**
{projectId: "...", description: "...", longitude: 10, latitude: 10, … }

*should actually be:*
projectId=...description=...longitude=10latitude=10...

-> In Postman everyhting works fine.

Comment: Try `JSON.stringify(prams)` inside you request

Comment: Transmitting data in JSON is the standard. Do you want them form-encoded ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not obvious, but you are not using the `httpClient` in the right way.

You can find this situation explained in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46714480/httpclient-post-request-using-x-www-form-urlencoded).

If you don't want to use JSON but want to stick with `x-www-form` encoding, Your code should look like:

```js
const body = new HttpParams()
  .set('your property name', ** property value **)
  .set(...);

return this.http.post(this.conf.url,
  body.toString(),
  {
    headers: new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
  }
).pipe(... same code as you already have ...);
```

Comment: Thank you, Mic. Your approach is the right way? Or is there a better way?

Comment: I think it's more natural to stick to JSON, as it is now the widespread standard. So, if you don't require `x-www-form`, just let Angular standard library do its fun with `content-type` being `application/json`. That way, the receiving end knows how to decode the payload (JSON.decode, or similar depending on the language). Check out the Angular doc on HttpClient for examples: https://angular.io/guide/http

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that Angular sends a post request of type JSON by default.

Either you change your PHP backend and instead using `$_POST` you can read the JSON:

```php
<?
..
$JSON = file_get_contents("php://input");
if (!empty($JSON ))
{
  $params = json_decode($JSON, true); 
}
?>
```

Or if you really want to relay on sending as `x-www-form-urlencoded`
you can use **`URLSearchParams`** which automatically set the content type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`:

```js
let body = new URLSearchParams();
body.set('username', username);
body.set('password', password);

this.http.post(this.loginUrl, body).map(...);
```

Of course you can do it also manually if you encode your body correctly like this

```
let body = `username=${username}&password=${password}`;
```

but you then have to set your headers manually to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Like this

```
this.http.post(this.loginUrl, body, { headers: headers }).map(...);
```

Comment: Hi xzesstence, thank you. Could you recommend a better way? In that way it sounds like a hotchpotch. What's the state of art?

Comment: since your are using angular, i recommend to use json and change the backend as i stated before, its simple and easy to use.

if it helped, im very thankful if you mark it as answer.
if you have further questions, just ask :)
Cheers

Comment: You've helped me both. Can't deciding by marking :-)

Comment: [This answer is being discussed on meta.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381420/receiving-2-reputation-in-several-answers)

Comment: @xzesstence looking at your activity page I see you have a series of downvotes. I think you are being targeted by a single user. You can flag this answer and pick "in need of moderator intervention" and describe your issue.

Comment: Thank you @ArunaHerath i will give it a try!